# Python Telegram bot that gets stats from Scrapy

Tags: python-3.x, scrapy, twisted, python-telegram-bot

I'd like to write a Telegram bot which can provide Scrapy stats **on request**.
My try mostly works, the only issue is that forcefully closing the spider (obviously) doesn't stop the bot.

So I have two questions :

- is my general approach the correct one?
- is it possible to close the bot even on forceful shutdown of the spider?

Here is the relevant class:

```
class TelegramBot(object):
    telegram_token = telegram_credentials.token

    @classmethod
    def from_crawler(cls, crawler):
        return cls(crawler)

    def __init__(self, crawler):
        self.crawler = crawler

        cs = crawler.signals
        cs.connect(self._spider_closed, signal=signals.spider_closed)

        """Start the bot."""
        # Create the Updater and pass it your bot's token.
        # Make sure to set use_context=True to use the new context based callbacks
        # Post version 12 this will no longer be necessary
        self.updater = Updater(self.telegram_token, use_context=True)

        # Get the dispatcher to register handlers
        dp = self.updater.dispatcher

        # on different commands - answer in Telegram
        dp.add_handler(CommandHandler("stats", self.stats))

        # Start the Bot
        self.updater.start_polling()

    def _spider_closed(self, spider, reason):
        # Stop the Bot
        self.updater.stop()

    def stats(self, update, context):
        # Send a message with the stats
        msg = (
            "Spider "
            + self.crawler.spider.name
            + " stats: "
            + str(self.crawler.stats.get_stats())
        )

        update.message.reply_text(msg)
```

Here you can find my full code inside the Scrapy tutorial quotes spider https://github.com/jtommi/scrapy_telegram-bot_example/blob/master/tutorial/tutorial/telegram-bot.py

My code is a combination of

- latencies extension from the "Learning Scrapy" book https://github.com/scalingexcellence/scrapybook/blob/master/ch09/properties/properties/latencies.py
- echobot example from the python-telegram-bot library https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/blob/master/examples/echobot.py
- official scrapy documentation on stats collection https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/stats.html

Answer (score 0):

Calling the `updater.stop()` will definitely stop the bot. From the docs of `python-telegram-bot`,

```
 """Stops the polling/webhook thread, the dispatcher and the job queue."""
```

Check if `updater.stop()` is called after spider closes. Bot might not stop immediately, but eventually will stop.

Comment: I think the issue here is not the bot, but Scrapy.  
The bot gets stopped when _spider_closed gets called.
But when I hit Ctrl-C twice, the spider is not closed cleanly, so the bot isn't stopped.  
The question is if there is a way to run code in the event where I hit Ctrl-C twice

Comment: You could make use of KeyboardInterrupt. When you hit Ctrl-C, KeyboardInterrupt exception will be raised, you could catch this exception within code, and gracefully stop the spider.